# Using uri() method twice inside .route() method in spring-cloud-gateway

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-cloud

Is it ok to invoke the `.uri()` method twice within a route?

I have done this and it seems to be working:

```
    @Bean
public RouteLocator gatewayRoutes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
    return builder.routes()
                  .route(r -> r.path("/api/q-bank/user/**") //intercept calls to
                               .uri("http://q-bank.cloud.host/")
                               .uri("http://localhost:8761/")
                               .id("userModule"))
```

But I am not sure that using `.uri()` twice is appropriate.

Comment: it is not. It will use the last one.

Comment: yes it will execute the last one